# How to disable (turn off) tripwire

Tags: linux, intrusion-detection

I setup a IDS [Tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/) and now found that sometimes when it check integrity of FS it's have huge CPU consumption. In all manuals only says how to setup this, but not how to delete.

I have root permissions, cause this is my server. How I may turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

I forget that I install tripwire via apt-get :) 
That's why I found the answer by myself

```
sudo apt-get remove tripwire
```